# File pathing on a 'header.php' that is i placed on an include() function on different folders

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap, filepath

I'm having a difficulty analyzing the correct file pathing on my 'header.php' which contains a 'login.php' link. I placed this 'header.php' on an 'include()' function.

THIS IS A SNIPPET OF MY 'header.php':

```
<div class="button navbar-right">
        <a href="../login.php"><button class="navbar-btn nav-button wow bounceInRight login" id="login">Login</button></a>
        <button class="navbar-btn nav-button wow fadeInRight" id="register" >Register</button>
    </div>
```

How should I correctly write my ... code wherein I can redirect to login.php regardless of the current folder that I'm in.

THIS IS MY 'index.php' code (note that 'index.php' and 'header.php' are in the same folder) I placed an 'include()' function so I won't have to code the exact same header for each files:

```
<?php include ('Header.php');?>
    <body>
        <div class="slider-area">
            <div class="slider">
               <div id="bg-slider" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
                <div class="item"><img src="" alt=""></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slider-content">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-18">
                    <h2>CHANGE STARTS HERE</h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eligendi deserunt deleniti, ullam commodi sit ipsam laboriosam velit adipisci quibusdam aliquam teneturo!</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
<script src="../bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

but since the path is '../login.php' I get redirected to a different path instead an I get an "Object not Found".... but when I go to another file that is another folder and click on LOGIN, I get redirected to the correct page.

How do I solve this? What should be my correct path?

Comment: Use the absolute path. `/login.php`.

Comment: that's the thing, whenever I go to a different folder, I get the wrong path.

Comment: If you use the absolute path you won't.